# GRAPH with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe :

```
year = c(rep(1998,4),rep(2000,5),rep(2002,2),rep(2004,2))
gift = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
type = c("L","L","L","H","H","L","L","L","L","L","H","L","L")
data = as.data.frame(cbind(anno,gift,type))
```

I have to create a graph with `ggplot` ,with x = year , y = probability of gift=1 and two type of points, one for type = L and one for type = H. So for each year I need two points, one that shows probability of gift = 1 for L and one that shows probability of gift=1 for H
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the probability you can calculate the mean for each `year` and `type` and use it in `ggplot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  group_by(year, type) %>%
  summarise(prob = mean(gift == 1)) %>%
  #If you have only 1/0 values in gift
  #summarise(prob = mean(gift)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(year, prob, color = type) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Ronak, it works, the only problem is that I need on the Y axis the probability for each type. So basically I need that on the Y axis appears the proportion of individual that receive a gift in a certain year for each type.

Comment: @leonardo Sorry `y` axis should be `prob`. I accidentally included `type`. I have corrected my answer above.